# Placement of table of contents in memoir document

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I have in the past used the `book` document style to create two books but I am trying the `memoir` style this time around.
For the title page, instead of using `\maketitle`, I copied (and adapted) the code for Peter Wilson's "titleTH" style (A.2 on p. 47 of *Some Examples of Title Pages* - I can't reconstruct how I found that document, though I know it was from a link in the `memoir` manual).

When I then followed that code with `\tableofcontents` the contents appeared at the bottom of the title page. To fix this, I inserted a `\newpage` which got rid of that problem but introduced a new one.  I want my chapters to open verso (`\openleft`), but the `\newpage` seems to make the contents open recto. I suspect I should have enclosed the title page code in some command to avoid this.
How do I fix this?

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass[openleft]{memoir}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Lecture}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\raggedleft
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
{\LARGE Zbigniew Nitecki}\\[0.167\textheight]
%{\bfseries The Big Book of}\\[\baselineskip]
{\textcolor{red}{\HUGE C\OE UR d'ANALYSE}}\\[\baselineskip]
{\Large 26 Lectures on Convergence and Continuity\\
with Discussions, Developments, and Diversions}\par
\vfill
{\Large Department of Mathematics \\ Tufts University }\par
\vspace*{3\baselineskip}

\newpage

\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\part{The Real Numbers}
\raggedright

\input{Inequalities}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\cleardoublepage` instead of `\newpage`?

Answer (score 1):

Below is an extended version of your MWE which now includes chapters.

```
% memopenprob.tex  SE 578347

% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass[openleft]{memoir}
%\documentclass[openleft]{book}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Lecture}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\raggedleft
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
{\LARGE Zbigniew Nitecki}\\[0.167\textheight]
%{\bfseries The Big Book of}\\[\baselineskip]
{\textcolor{red}{\HUGE C\OE UR d'ANALYSE}}\\[\baselineskip]
{\Large 26 Lectures on Convergence and Continuity\\
with Discussions, Developments, and Diversions}\par
\vfill
{\Large Department of Mathematics \\ Tufts University }\par
\vspace*{3\baselineskip}

%\newpage          %%%%% deleted
\cleardoublepage   %%%%% added

\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\part{The Real Numbers}
\raggedright

%%%%%% following changed/added
%\input{Inequalities}
\chapter{Inequalities}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Equalities}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The `\part` page always starts on a verso page followed by a blank page (the same as in the `book` class). Following from that a `\chapter` starts on a verso page, as requested by the `openleft` class option.

Note that the `openleft` option applies to chapters, not parts.

Comment: Thanks.  \cleardoublepage did exactly what I needed.